# VOID function passes array by reference, but when used, I get "No matching matching function for call to..."

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference, void

I wrote the following code to fill a `double` array of length `len` (that has already been initialized) with random floating point numbers:

```
void FillRay(double (&array)[] , const unsigned int len, const double a , const double b)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i )
    {
    array[i] = randFloat(a,b);   // Fill array at i with random number
    }

return;
}
```

However, when I use my `FillRay` function in `main()` (see end of main)...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    double a;
    double b;

    cout << "Please enter lower bound (a): ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please enter upper bound (b): ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << endl;

    //Calculate mean and variance
    double mu = (b - a)/2;
    double sigma = pow(b - a , 2)/12;

    //Declare arrays (with langths)
    unsigned int shorter = 1000;
    unsigned int longer = 100000;
    double shortArray[shorter];
    double longArray[longer];

    // Fill array of length 1K
    FillRay(shortArray , shorter, a , b);    // ***THIS IS MY PROBLEM AREA***

    return 0;
}
```

... I get the error **No matching function for call to 'FillRay'**

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong??  Thanks!

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are not standard C++ although your compiler may support it as an extension. Use at your own peril.

Comment: Where do you define the function `FillRay`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your function prototype to following:

```
void FillRay(double* array, const unsigned int len, const double a , const double b)
```

Also, it is a good practice to use size_t instead of int for array sizes.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> void FillRay(double (&array)[] , const unsigned int len, const double a , const double b)
> ```

`double (&array)[]` is an attempt to take an array by reference without specifying the array's size. This is not possible. The fact that you also specify a `len` parameter is technically irrelevant. If you want to use standard C++ without any proprietary extensions, then you have three choices:

1. Completely change the program logic such that the array size is fixed at compile time.
2. Have the function take a `double*` and let the automatic conversion (informally called "decay") from array to pointer take place.
3. Use `std::vector<double>`.